# How to get a list of all database names in FileMaker pro using ODBC C#

Tags: c#, odbc, filemaker

I am working on an application to extract data from FileMaker pro using ODBC, I successfully get data from a specific table now

```
    try
    {
        conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=FileMaker;Uid=Admin;Pwd=******");
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM SimpleProductTest");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if ((dr != null) && (dr.HasRows))
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                    temp = dr.GetString(0);
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Now I want to list all database names and table names in FileMaker Pro. Based on their document(http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.31.html), function DatabaseNames seems to be the right one.

```
try
{
    conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=FileMaker;Uid=Admin;Pwd=******");
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new OdbcCommand("DatabaseNames");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    if ((dr != null) && (dr.HasRows))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            temp = dr.GetString(0);
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, I get exceptions that query is not right, does anyone know how to list all databases and tables in FileMaker Pro?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need their SQL reference, if you're querying through ODBC. The internal functions can be used only within the Filemaker application itself.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I went though their ODBC query and there is no command to get all databases or tables. Thanks for telling me the fact that internal functions can be used only within the Filemaker application itself. I will check on their forum for more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker functions only work in FileMaker, including FSQL calls, as far as I know. Here is a link to the ODBC guide (pdf) from FileMaker:

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fm13_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf

You may want to refer to chapter 7, for reference information. FileMaker exposes itself to ODBC with the table occurrence names in it's relationship graph, not the actual table names. You should be able to return all available tables from there. In general you will know the database or file name you are trying to access, and the authentication needed as well.

Each individual file is roughly equivalent to a "database" in SQL parlance. I don't know if there is a SQL statement that will return all available databases, but you should be able to see what files are open from the FM Server admin console.

Comment: "*You should be able to return all available tables from there.*" Where exactly is "there"?

Answer (score 7):

Come to think of it, this function is undocumented. Try `FileMaker_Tables` (and its companion  `FileMaker_Fields`). These work within the internal  ExecuteSQL() function. I suppose they are also available through ODBC, but I don't know that for sure (and have no way to find out ATM).

`FileMaker_Tables` returns the following columns:

1. TableName
2. TableID
3. BaseTableName
4. BaseFileName
5. ModCount

Credit:
http://www.databuzz.com.au/using-executesql-to-query-the-virtual-schemasystem-tables/

Comment: I tested this function, it does not work. I am trying to use ODBC catalog function, but no luck so far. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: This worked fine for me via ODBC - I wish this showed the base tables rather than the instances though, and there was a way to access those directly rather than via the "table instances"

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  `SELECT * FROM FileMaker_Fields` yields the result desired.